# EXCEL formula column how to return cell reference

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

The values in columns `E:G` are calculated from data in columns `A:D`. The respective formulas are as follows:

```
E=A+B
F=B*C*D
G=D-C-B
```

The excel sheet looks as follows:

[image: data]

Assume I want to find which formula column is used in the column `B`, in other words, I want to know the formulas of `E`, `F`, `G` that contain column `B`.

I know two ways to achieve this:

[image: first way]

[image: second way]

Is there another way to find it? For example, looking as follows:

[image: need]

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to see the formulas which are being used. Is it not acceptable to click on the cell and then look at the formula listed in the value bar above the spreadsheet, under the ribbon?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is use of Col B only restricted to formulas in cols E F G or there could be more?  Explore FORMULATEXT function here, it might help.

Comment: Yes. I want to see the formulas which are being used!

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/display-or-hide-formulas-f7f5ab4e-bf24-4efc-8fc9-0c1b77a5356f ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach to tackle this issue could be the combination of different functions, i.e., `IF()`, `ISNUMBER()`, `SEARCH()`, and `FORMULATEXT()`.

For the example, I take the data as given by you in the columns `A:D`, and the formulas in columns `E:G`. In addition, to demonstrate that the formula works as intended, I also added the `formula4 = A+C` in column `H`.

Now, to check if the different formulas include the column B, you can use the following approach:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($J2,FORMULATEXT(E2))),"Yes","No")
```

The data and output looks as follows:
[image: data and output]

Using the `FORMULATEXT()` function you return the formula that is used in a specific column. You use this as an input in the `SEARCH()` function where you search for "B", which is stored in cell `J2`. However, instead of using `$J2`, you could also use a hardcoded "B" in the function. Since the search function returns the position of the match, you need to transform it with the `ISNUMBER()` function into a binary 0/1, which is subsequently used in the `IF()` function. Right now, the function returns "Yes", if column `B` is used, and "No" if column `B` is not used. This can be adjusted according to your needs.

---

This approach works in the scenario that you outlined above. However, for completeness, I also want to mention one caveat in this approach. In the way the search function is currently specified, it simply looks for "B" in the formula. However, if you have much more columns, and the formula is stored, e.g., in column `AB`, the function will also return a match. If you end up in this situation, you might need to tweak a bit the specific search function, but in your scenario it is not necessary to make things overly complex.